# Creating Checkbox Site-Columns in SharePoint using Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

[image]

I am new to SharePoint. I am facing difficulties on creating site columns for the above scenario please suggest me how to do this one:

I have 10 check boxes and  corresponding two text boxes to enter number of days and comments. how should I create this type of site columns..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create simple choice field which will have 10 options: Annual, Long Service and etc. so you will be able to save each item in the list the same way you want. To create choice field definition here is an example:

```
<Field ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}"
     Name="LeaveType"
     DisplayName="Type"
     Type="Choice"
     Required="TRUE"
     Group="Leave columns">
<CHOICES>
  <CHOICE>Annual</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Long Service</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>...</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
```

Comment: Thank You.. But I have to select multiple options.. and for each selected check box, i need to fill other corresponding text boxes like number of days and comments..

Comment: So each row would be separate list item. Its the matter of data model design. What I am suggesting is to write some CRUD web part or control with such UI you have provided which will be saving each line as a separate list item and you can group them by having user field on your list, but if this is not an option for you when you need to write custom field. Here is an example how you can achieve this goal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861799(v=office.14).aspx 
or you can google with kword: "developing SharePoint custom field types" there is a lot of blog posts about this.